# Photoshop - How to create master/detail pages?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am skinning up a website and other things in Photoshop but I am finding the PSD taking a very long time to load/save and I'm wanting to split the PSD file into several files.

I've done this, but sometimes I need to adjust one thing and I have to change every PSD file so that the entire project is consistent.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to create a master/detail (or a template) structure using Photoshop.

What is the best way to achieve this goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My advice is create a Photoshop Action(sort of macro) which makes what you need, thinking while making it in not add any too specific step that will only work with certain file, and then use File/Automate/Batch. There, set the input and output folders, and set PSD as format to output.